# Ionic app not working on device/simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

It was working fine in the simulator yesterday but now it's acting goofy. I happened to stumble on a way to get it working in the simulator though:

Normally to simulate the app on ios I run

```
$ ionic run ios
```

Which now shows the app but the "broken" version of it.

However, if I run

```
$ ionic run ios --livereload
```

Then my app works as expected! Unfortunately the *ionic view* app displays the broken version. Chrome (via `ionic serve`) shows the working version so I'm using that to develop now but I need to get this fixed. What's the troubleshooting process at this point?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Even though this *worked* on the web along with `--livereload` the issue all along was with a script href url.

**The problem:** The google maps `js` link was using "//url.to.site" so I had to manually prepend "http:" and voila.

## How to properly debug ionic + angularjs apps on iOS devices

**Debugging** this was *terrible* until I came with up a *good* solution. **Beware:** this *requires* OS X or some serious hacking skills.

**Here are the steps in order:**

1. `$ ionic build ios`
2. Open `TheApp/platforms/ios/TheApp.xcworkspace` in `Xcode`
3. Build/Run the app in xcode to device OR simulator
4. Open **Safari** w/ *Developer Mode* enabled (Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar)
5. In the **Safari** menu select `Debug` > `[Name of iOS device]` > `index.html`
6. While the **Inspector** window is active, hit **CMD+R** (*refresh*) and you'll be able to watch your `console.logs` from the beginning of the *page load*.

**EDIT** Shortcut: You can skip steps 1-3 if you use `$ ionic run ios --device`

This is **awesome** because now you can step through your code on an actual iOS device! I hope this will save some of you heaps of time. Best of luck!

## For Android Devices

Thanks to @sajclarke I found this article: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks. You can do the same debugging on Android via Chrome browser > Inspect devices once the device is connected via USB and the app has debug mode enabled.

Comment: HUGE!! What a monster tip! I'd spent an hour trying to track down the tiniest of errors and I found it in 10 seconds thanks to the Console output in Safari's Developer Tools. +1

Comment: This helped me so much. THANK YOU!